# consecutive statements on a line must be separated by :

Tags: swift

I'm just try below code its giving error as **consecutive statements on a line must be separated by :** and also **use of unresolved 'nsurlReq**

not sure why its throwing error ..

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webview1: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.x`

        // here use NSURL for initializing any url

        let urlValue = NSURL(string: "http://bing.com");

        // load it in web view


        NSURLRequest nsurlReq = NSURLRequest ( URL : urlValue! );

        webview1.loadRequest ( nsurlReq );


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
NSURLRequest nsurlReq = NSURLRequest ( URL : urlValue! );
```

is using Objective C syntax - it should be instead:

```
let nsurlReq: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest ( URL : urlValue! )
```

or, taking advantage of type inference:

```
let nsurlReq = NSURLRequest(URL: urlValue!)
```

Note: I've used `let` instead of `var` because I presume `nsurlReq` won't be modified after its initial assignment, so it's better to make it immutable. Change to mutable otherwise.